# Facebook Admin ID for already existing page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new on Facebook and I have one issue: I have my own account on FB and I've added page for one of my online tools, today I don't know where I can find my Admin ID to place it in `<meta property="fb:admins"...>` tag related to my FB page. I've found link to FB Insights but I see only links to create new app or new page and I don't see my already existing page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your own user_id as admin_id, use

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname

to query for your user_id.

Comment: I found another solution by clicking on "Update Info" button and then in "Contact Information" area, Facebook email address contains my user_id as name part, eg. 123456789@facebook.com